# Filter through plain object key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JS Object of the form stored in a variable `keyData`:

```
{type: "", label: "fname", title: "first name", …}
    defaultvalue: ""
    disabled: false
    label: "fname"
    readonly: false
    required: "on"
    title: "first name"
    type: ""
    __proto__: Object
```

I want to filter through these key-value pair and return a new object which contains the key-value pair with data available in them. For example, in this data, it should return **title, required, and label** only.

With that new filtered data, I want to map a react form with filtered keys as input types and filtered values as their value.

I am confused on how to solve this. I tried using **Object.entries(keyData)**
like this:

```
   Object.entries(keyData).filter(x => console.log(x))
   console.log(keyData)
```

on the `console.log(keyData)`, it prints:

```
(2) ["type", ""]
(2) ["label", "fname"]
(2) ["title", "first name"]
(2) ["placeholder", ""]
(2) ["required", "on"]
(2) ["readonly", false]
(2) ["disabled", false]
```

I am unable to filter through this empty data further.

Comment: For future reference, it would be helpful to paste the JSON or JS object representation of your input.

Comment: It's not JSON if you're going to run `Object.entries` on it. JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `reduce` after you use `Object.entries`. You can then return an object only when the `value` is truthy.

```js
const data = {
  a: "foo",
  b: false,
  c: "bar",
  d: null
};

const filtered = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (value) {
    acc[key] = value;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: But I also need to use these keys to dynamically render react form input types. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @bubble-cord I believe you should just be able to map over your filtered object at this point

Answer (score 2):

You need `filter()` and then `reduce()` to make it object

```
Object.entries(keyData).filter((key, value) => value).reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr[0]] = curr[1];
  return prev;
}, {});
```